# Android Call Log History app

Tags: android

How can I do this? I wanna to add my phone call log app, the time (start and end), and if the photo and name already have in phone contact, I wanna to add this photo and name in my app. if not I want to set default photo. And I wanna show phone number.

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CallLog;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView PhoneNumber = null;
    TextView Date = null;
//  TextView StartEnd = null;
    TextView Duration = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        PhoneNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNumber);
        Date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
    //  StartEndTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtStartEnd);
        Duration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDuration);

        getCallDetails();
    }

    private void getCallDetails() {

        StringBuffer sbPhoneNumber = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer sbDate = new StringBuffer();
        // StringBuffer sbStart = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer sbDuration = new StringBuffer();

        Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);

        int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);

        while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String phNum = managedCursor.getString(number);
            String callTypeCode = managedCursor.getString(type);
            String strcallDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
            Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(strcallDate));
            String dateStr = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(callDayTime);

            String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);

            String callType = null;
            int callcode = Integer.parseInt(callTypeCode);
            switch (callcode) {
            case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                callType = "Outgoing";
                break;
            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                callType = "Incoming";
                break;
            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                callType = "Missed";
                break;
            }
            sbPhoneNumber.append(phNum + " (" + callType + ") ");
            sbDate.append(dateStr);
            sbDuration.append(callDuration);

        }
        managedCursor.close();
        PhoneNumber.setText(sbPhoneNumber);
        Date.setText(sbDate);
        Duration.setText(sbDuration);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the problem your facing , Are you getting any error?

Comment: About the code isn't error. Moreover, I want to add Start Time & End Time, Photo & Phone Number (if have in phone contact), if not, default ..

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Currently your using **Call Log API ** to retrieve  the log history , I would suggest you to use **ContactsContract API** to retrieve the associated phone number and photo of that number as shown below.

Let us for retrieving photo from Contacts we can write a method as

```
  private void retrieveContactPhoto() {

            Bitmap photo = null;

            try {
// contacts API
                InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getContentResolver(),
                        ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new Long(contactID)));

                if (inputStream != null) {
                    photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_contact);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                }

                assert inputStream != null;
                inputStream.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Step 2: Similarly for Contact Number

```
private void retrieveContactNumber() {

        String contactNumber = null;

        // getting contacts ID
        Cursor cursorID = getContentResolver().query(uriContact,
                new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID},
                null, null, null);

        if (cursorID.moveToFirst()) {

            contactID = cursorID.getString(cursorID.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        }

        cursorID.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "Contact ID: " + contactID);

        // Using the contact ID now we will get contact phone number
        Cursor cursorPhone = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},

                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = " +
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE,

                new String[]{contactID},
                null);

        if (cursorPhone.moveToFirst()) {
            contactNumber = cursorPhone.getString(cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        }

        cursorPhone.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "Contact Phone Number: " + contactNumber);
    }
```

Step 3: For retriving Contact Name

```
private void retrieveContactName() {

    String contactName = null;

    // querying contact data store
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriContact, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        // DISPLAY_NAME = The display name for the contact.
        // HAS_PHONE_NUMBER =   An indicator of whether this contact has at least one phone number.

        contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }

    cursor.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "Contact Name: " + contactName);

}
```

Step4: In order to use contacts you have to set permission in Android Manifest file as shown below.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Comment: @Pyae Phyo: If this answer is correct and helpful to you , please upvote and accept by clicking the ticket mark below to  vote option., so that others facing this problem ion future may give a try to correct answers and also for you to gain reputation, and make others to answer your question, accepts the good answers of your questions.